# Ektron 9 - Changing default site language

Tags: localization, ektron

Ektron 9 SP2 - 9.0.0.249

We are trying to change the default language to en-GB site-wide. This is what we tried:

1. Set `English (UK) en-GB` as enabled language in Settings-L10n-Lanugages and Regions
2. Set en-GB as default language in Settings-Setup-Default Application Language
3. Edited web.config `<add key="ek_DefaultContentLanguage" value="1033" />` to `2057`

We did this and it did not work, so rolled the changes back to find that all items allocated to taxonomies has disappeared. Luckily we had a database backup that we deployed.

Has anyone else tried this? What is the correct way?

Cheers

Comment: "It did not work" - What were you expecting the outcome to be and what did you see that indicated it did not work?

Comment: Thought there may be a clever conversion tool, but judging from anser below it is a manual process. Will post back if have any other info. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default language is set using the key in the web.config file as you say.  This only changes what the default is, i.e. the language you get without explicitly selecting one. Any existing content you have is not automatically translated.

The process should be this:

1) Enable English UK in Settings > Localization > Languages and Regions.  Important to leave English US enabled for now.

2) Create English UK versions of your content.  You can do this either by using the XLIFF feature or by doing it one content item at a time (go to the content item in the workarea, select the target language in the Add drop down list.

3) You will also need to ensure you have English UK versions of Taxonomies, Metadata, Menus, etc.

4) Change the default language value to "2057" in web.config using the ek_DefaultContentLanguage key.

5) Check your content appears.

6) Disable English US (if necessary).

Regarding the items that disappeared, I wonder if you had disabled English US when you enabled English UK?  That might have caused this to happen.

Comment: Thanks for that, will try and double check what we did.